# BackboneJS: When to use fetch and when to use sync?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web-frontend

I see that Backbone.JS offers two methods of syncing the data from backend: fetch and sync.
From their documentation, fetch can also be used as sync:

> The behavior of fetch can be customized by using the available set options. For example, to fetch a collection, getting an "add" event for every new model, and a "change" event for every changed existing model, without removing anything: collection.fetch({remove: false})

Can someone please explain when to use which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) is an underlying method used to interact (create/read/update/delete) with the server. `Fetch` is a subset of `sync`, used only to pull (read) data from the server. You *can* use `sync` exclusively, but you'd find that you'd need to do extra work every time you wanted to simply retrieve the model/collection.

In practice, I rarely need to use `sync`. Instead, I rely on `fetch`, `save` and `destroy` - all of which delegate to the underlying `sync` method.